# javascript, php not saving text to file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a webpage with a signup form which takes an email and a password. The html calls javascript function which in return calls php code that saves the email to a file on the server. It seems the javascript is working fine but the php code doesn't save to file.

Any suggestions on what's going wrong would be appreciated.

**Javascript snippet:**

```
$("#signup-divider").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        email: $("#signup-email").val(),
        password: $("#signup-password").val()
    };

    if ( isValidEmail(data['email']) && (data['password'].length > 1)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/php/subscribe.php",
            data: data,
            success: function() {
                $('.signup-success').fadeIn(1000);
                $('.signup-failed').fadeOut(0);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.signup-failed').fadeIn(1000);
        $('.signup-success').fadeOut(500);
    }

    return false;
});
```

**subscribe.php :**

```
<?php
//This Script only check Email Address and add it to email-list.txt

$email = trim($_POST['email']);

// Email address validation - works with php 5.2+
function is_email_valid($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}  

if ( isset($email) && is_email_valid($email) ) {
    file_put_contents("email-list.txt", "$email\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

?>
```

Edit: Please note that this is test code. I plan to replace the text file with email notifications and remove passwords. I'm taking a stock template which I don't understand very well and modifying it.

Comment: Webserver on Linux? If so, check the file's permission, the any.txt, might need to be 0755 or maybe even 0777 depending on the server's setup.

Comment: Where is `$anuwoshere` defined? Is the PHP executing without any errors? You are trimming the email before checking if it is set so that could cause an *Undefined index error* and will prevent the script from continuing its execution.

Comment: Yes, it was permissions on the text file. chmod 777 worked fine! 755 didn't. Thanks very much. That was big help.

Comment: @Script47 $anuwoshere was test code that I accidently left in when I wrote this message. Its not actually in the live code. But thanks for looking through it. I tested other php code which executes fine. The issue was file permissions as above.

Comment: @Santy Do you want to write the answer in and I'll mark it as complete?

Comment: 777 for text file with passwords? If anything, you should be using 600/644 for this. I hope you're using a really BIG lock for this (htaccess). Why aren't you using a database for this? Text files are so much work to maintain for stuff like this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, this is test code. I plan to replace the text file with email notifications and remove passwords. We're a small startup with resource constraints so I'm taking a stock template which I don't understand very well and modifying it.

Comment: You're welcome and *stay safe* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webserver on Linux? If so, check the file's permission, the `any.txt`, might need to be `0755` or maybe even `0777` depending on the server's setup. ;)

You do have to consider security, especially if you are on shared hosting.
`0777` might make the file readable by other users on the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $file = fopen("sdf/sdf/file.txt", "a") or die("Error");
        $txt = "asdfasdfasdfasdfadf";
        fwrite($file, $txt);
        fclose($file);
        // Permissions.
        chmod($file, 0775) // unix / linux- 0777 didn't work for me.
```

My main server requires the zero. Some don't. Make sure that is there.